# draw line over uilable after loading from nib

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nib, drawrect

here is my code

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(c);
CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 277.0f, 21.0f);
CGFloat newpoint = 277.0f + (CGFloat)(self.msrp.text.length * 8);
//NSLog(@"%f", newpoint);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, newpoint, 21.0f);
CGContextStrokePath(c);
```

i am trying to draw a line over UIlabel, i am loading my view from nib.i dont know what i am doing wrong. i just work fine if i  draw entire view instead loading from nib.(but i dont wanna do that)..i hope my question is clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok , finally i end up subclassing UIlabel. and then place my code in drawTextInRect.